# How can i add items to a listbox on the same line (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I want to make it so that each Time it goes through the for loop, it places the value on the same line, but I don't know how. Can someone help?

Edit: i'm trying to set up an address book type code, for an assignment, and i want to display the output so all J outputs are on the same line of of the listbox.

Here is the code which will declare what each number of J is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    i += 1
    j = 0
    AddressArray(i, j) = TxtFirstName.Text   
    j += 1

    AddressArray(i, j) = TxtLastName.Text 

    j += 1

    If TxtHomePhone.Text = "" Then              
        AddressArray(i, j) = "N/A"
        j += 1
    Else
        AddressArray(i, j) = TxtHomePhone.Text
        j += 1
    End If
    If TxtMobilePhone.Text = "" Then           
        AddressArray(i, j) = "N/A"
        j += 1
    Else
        AddressArray(i, j) = TxtMobilePhone.Text
        j += 1
    End If
    AddressArray(i, j) = TxtHomeNumb.Text       
    j += 1
    AddressArray(i, j) = TxtStName.Text         
    j += 1

    AddressArray(i, j) = TxtSuburb.Text    

    For j = 0 To 6
        LstAddresses.Items.Add(AddressArray(i, j))

    Next
End Sub
```

The for loop is to print it out and i'll give a picture of the output on the form to give what i want and what is given: (i've read from a file using streamreader as input for the listbox as the test data)

[The form of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgWOy.png)

Comment: Post your source code, not a screenshot.

Comment: What does "on the same line" actually mean? An answer has been provided that will insert a new item above all the existing items. That's one interpretation. It might also be that you want the new data combined on the same line as an existing item.  It's up to you to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. The more you leave open to interpretation, the better chance we will interpret incorrectly and waste our time and yours providing irrelevant advice.

Comment: Sorry i was unclear, i meant on the same line on the listbox (output) so each time it goes through the for loop, it would print the output on the same line of the listbox.

Comment: jmc gave you some very clear wording.  And your response is to reiterate and repeat the ambiguous wording that caused the misunderstanding in the first place.  You can see how this could be very frustrating for us, yes?

Comment: Your comment does not clarify the totally unclear question you've asked. Please [edit] your post and make it more clear what specifically you are asking. What does *on the same line of the listbox* mean? If you want a single item in the listbox, concatenate the strings ahead of time and add them as a single item. If you mean something else, then clearly explain (in your question via an [edit], not in a comment) what it is you're trying to do. And post code as text, not as an image. Copy/paste it directly from your code editor.

Comment: Sorry everyone who tried helping me, but due to my poor explanation skills, couldn't. Just wanted to let you know i solved my problem by doing what Ken White told me to do by concatenating the strings before putting them in. Really appreciate the help! (sorry again!!)

Comment: Ah.. just posted an answer before I read your above comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListBox.Items.Insert( 0, item )` instead of `ListBox.Items.Add( item )`.

The `Insert( index, item )` method, with `index: 0` which place them at the top of the collection.

Comment: Sorry, i may of been unclear with what i wanted and wasted some time, i'm new to this website.(i'll edit the question) What i'm trying to get is so the output of the For loop would appear in a single line of the Listbox, instead of appearing on each separate line. i'll put in some more code and try to give context, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should concatenate the relevant data into a single string and then add that string to your ListBox ..

```
Dim data As String = ""
Dim loopEnd As Integer = 6
For j As Integer = 0 To loopEnd
    If j < loopEnd Then
        data = data & AddressArray(i, j) & ", "
    Else
        data = data & AddressArray(i, j)
    End If
Next
LstAddresses.Items.Add(data)
```

Don't forget to add your own commas and spaces to the string

I would suggest that instead of storing the data in an array, define an address class with relevant properties and only use a single dimension array. It will make the code less error prone and much easier to maintain if you decide to change the number of fields in the address data.

In addition if `AddressArray` holds something like names or IDs in the 1st dimension, include that in your new `Address` class and instead of using an array at all, just use a `List (Of Address)` which will make it even easier to write code for and to maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!! this looks more efficient than what i did. thanks